# Is it possible to pass continuous data as input to an RBM model for unsupervised anomaly detection?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, rbm

Can we pass Continous data as input to RBM. I want to use RBM model for anomaly detection using unsupervised learning but as i know RBM model accepts the binary data but my dataset consists of geohash codes. Please suggest me a feasible approach.

tried passing continous data to rbm model

Comment: By RBM, do you mean Restricted Boltzmann machine ?